# running examples files with LIBSVM

Tags: python, libsvm

I have just installed LIBSVM and watched this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gePWtNAQcK8) to understand how to train and test datasets.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
Can't open input file a1a.train.
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: To me "the following youtube video" is not compatible with a link like "http://www.bing.com/videos/search?..."

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to train SVMs in Python then I recommend you using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html). It is the go to machine learning package within python with lots of documentation and support. It is also installable through [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) so it is easy to get it installed and running.

Sklearn has a specific [SVM module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm) that uses LIBSVM to do the backend work while sklearn does most of the data handling.

Here is a nice [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-regression-py) from sklearn for running your first SVM in python and sklearn.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate sample data
X = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis=0)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()
Add noise to targets
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))

# Fit regression model
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X, y).predict(X)
y_lin = svr_lin.fit(X, y).predict(X)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(X, y).predict(X)

# look at the results
lw = 2
plt.scatter(X, y, color='darkorange', label='data')
plt.hold('on')
plt.plot(X, y_rbf, color='navy', lw=lw, label='RBF model')
plt.plot(X, y_lin, color='c', lw=lw, label='Linear model')
plt.plot(X, y_poly, color='cornflowerblue', lw=lw, label='Polynomial model')
plt.xlabel('data')
plt.ylabel('target')
plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]